# Ubuntu system Working very slow

Tags: 14.04, dell

I have a Dell OPTIPLEX 380 CPU. It keeps on hanging only after running any 2-3 programmes simultaneously.

Here is the configuration

- RAM - **2GB**
- Processor- **core 2 duo**
- Hard Drive - **128 GB(HDD)**
- OS - **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

How can I fix it? 
We have work for at least 10 hours a day on this system.

Is increasing the RAM is the only option to fix it?

Comment: The hard drive is really an HDD or is it a SSD?

Comment: @MichaelBay it's HDD

Comment: Than it must be a very old one (and odd, never heard of a 128GB platter, only 100, 120, 200, 250,..., 128 is typical of many fairly recent SSDs though,hence the question). That alone can be a problem. Have you checked the disk for errors? But it also depends on what programs are running simultaneously. And you shouldn't be using the standard Ubuntu with such old system anyway. Lubuntu is the same but with a desktop environment that requires less resources, especially graphics.